# How to safely unpack dict in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a wrapper class - it's an abstraction that I return from backend to frontend.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class NewsItem(NamedTuple):
    id: str
    title: str
    content: str
    service: str
    published_at: datetime

    @classmethod
    def from_payload(cls, payload) -> 'NewsItem':
        return cls(**payload)
```

For example, when I get data from elastic I convert it to `NewsItem`:

```
return [NewsItem.from_payload(hit['_source'])
        for hit in result['hits']['hits']]
```

The problem is I don't want to fail because of unknown fields that can come from elastic. How to ignore them (or put into a separate dedicated attribute list `NewsItem.extra`)?

Comment: are you worried about key's in result dictionary?

Comment: yes, `hit['_source']` can contain some extra fields that don't exist in `NewsItem`. I want to ignore them and do not fail during `from_payload`

Comment: What is `NamedTuple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is to use `._fields` of `NewsItem`:

```
@classmethod
def from_payload(cls, payload) -> 'NewsItem':
    return cls(*(payload[field] for field in cls._fields))
```

If you want to keep extras, you would need to do some work (field `extra` declared as `extra: dict = {}`):

```
@classmethod
def from_payload(cls, payload) -> 'NewsItem':
    fields_no_extra = set(cls._fields) - {'extra'}
    extra_fields = payload.keys() - fields_no_extra
    extras = {field: payload[field] for field in extra_fields}
    data = {field: payload[field] for field in fields_no_extra}
    data['extra'] = extras
    return cls(**data)
```

You can optimize this further, too much computation with sets;)

Of course my solutions do not handle case where `payload` doesn't contain all of the fields of the `NewsItem`

Comment: "Of course my solutions do not handle case where `payload` doesn't contain all of the fields of the `NewsItem`" Yes it does, with minor change: `**{field: payload.get(field) for field in cls._fields}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**kwargs` to let your `__init__` take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments ("kwargs" means "keyword arguments") and discard unnecessary arguments:

```
class NewsItem(NamedTuple):
    id: str
    title: str
    content: str
    service: str
    published_at: datetime

    @classmethod
    def from_payload(cls, id=None, title=None, content=None, service=None, published_at=None, **kwargs) -> 'NewsItem':
        return cls(id, title, content, service, published_at)
```

Alternative solution with introspection `NamedTuple` class attributes (see @MOROZILnic answer + comment)

Comment: thanks, but I got `AttributeError: Cannot overwrite NamedTuple attribute __init__`

Comment: `from typing import NamedTuple`

Comment: @petrush see fix

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is with the unknown key's you can use get method of the dictionary to safely ignore unknown keys.

For get method, first argument is the key you are looking for and the second argument is the Default value which will be returned when the key is not found.

so, do the following

```
return [NewsItem.from_payload(hit['_source'])
        for hit in result.get('hits',{}).get('hits',"NOT FOUND"):
```

The above is just a example. do modify what you want to get when the hit does not have the key you want.

Comment: what if `hit['_source']` contains some other keys rather that (`id, title, content, service, published_at`)? I think your algorithm will fail too

Comment: hey, i was just telling you how to use fail-safe method while using dictionaries. so, when ever you are trying to access a key, use get method

Comment: i did mention that , that was just a example in the answer

Comment: So, if you want to do it for hit, just do , hit.get("_source","NA")

Comment: I've downvoted, as @petrush said you fail to answer the original question.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg, what did i miss?

Comment: Please explain what `result.get('hits',{})` does, as I don't see any mention of a `hits` key nor attribute anywhere

Comment: please do read last line of the answer. or my complete answer.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg, if you did read my answer, you would find the following text -- "For get method, first argument is the key you are looking for and the second argument is the Default value which will be returned when the key is not found."

Comment: You fail to understand the OP and you fail to understand the comments too!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173210/discussion-between-inaflash-and-benjamin-toueg).